fork vs vfork in process creation
As I know:
1- When calling vfork, parent waits until child is terminated (But when child invokes exec new address space will be made).
2- vfork does not use copy-on-write when creating child process. Both parent and child use the same addres space.
3- fork uses copy-on-write when creating child process.
In an operating system book (Operating system concept, ABRAHAM SILBERSCHATZ) I read that using vfork in shell is more efficient than fork. I don't understand why?
As I know, when using fork, before any changes, exec is called, so we don't have any changed page and we don't have any page copy (becuase of copy-on-write), therefore fork and vfork should have the same performance.

What is your question?

My question is, is vfork better than fork (in programs like shell), if yes, why?

From what I know:
vfork:

Share the memory space of the parent process with the child process

So all the process of allocating memory is avoided and the CPU has less things to compute.
This is the main reason why vfork is considered more efficient.
Fork is safer because of the 2 separate memory allocation. Each process has it's own and run in parrallel, they will not interfer or wait for the other.
VFork wait for the child process to exec or exit which lead to a more ordonnate execution but also more memory versability.

In conclusion Vfork is faster but Fork is safer
Source: Myself, AskDifference, TechDifferences
